# Error in render method of App.js? React-Native question

Tags: javascript, react-native

Pasted below is my code:

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, Flatlist, Alert} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
import {AddTask} from './src/screens/AddTask';
import {TaskList} from './src/screens/TaskList';

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([{id: uuidv4(), text: 'Task 1'}]);

  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    setTasks((prevTasks) => {
      return prevTasks.filter((task) => task.id != id);
    });
  };
  const addTask = (text) => {
    if (!text) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please enter a task', {text: 'Ok'});
    } else {
      setTask((prevTask) => {
        return [{id: uuid(), text}, ...prevTask];
      });
    }
  };

  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>
      <AddTask addTask={addTask} />
      <Flatlist
        data={tasks}
        renderItem={({task}) => (
          <TaskList item={task} deleteTask={deleteTask} />
        )}
      />
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

I get an error about my render method:
ERROR    Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in, or you might have mixed up default and named imports.

After Googling a bit people told me to check my imports, but I swear they are done correctly. Could someone help me understand this? I am building a task manager and I am looking to implement Redux later but I am simply seeking to build the app first: add redux later.

Full Github Project: https://github.com/calebdockal/TaskManagerApp2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are few changes to be done in the code.

In the import statement remove curly brackets around AddTask and TaskList

```
import AddTask from './src/screens/AddTask';
import TaskList from './src/screens/TaskList';
```

Change Flatlist to FlatList in import statement

```
import {View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert} from 'react-native';
```

and change in return statement. Then update variable in renderItem from task to item and item to task as show below

```
<FlatList data={tasks}
    renderItem={({item}) => (
        <TaskList task={item} deleteTask={deleteTask} />
    )}
/>
```

Full code below

```
import React, {useState} from 'react';
import {View, StyleSheet, FlatList, Alert, Text} from 'react-native';
import 'react-native-get-random-values';
import {v4 as uuidv4} from 'uuid';
import AddTask from './src/screens/AddTask';
import TaskList from './src/screens/TaskList';

const App = () => {
  const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([{id: uuidv4(), text: 'Task 1'}]);

  const deleteTask = (id) => {
    setTasks((prevTasks) => {
      return prevTasks.filter((task) => task.id != id);
    });
  };
  const addTask = (text) => {
    if (!text) {
      Alert.alert('Error', 'Please enter a task', {text: 'Ok'});
    } else {
      setTasks((prevTask) => {
        return [{id: uuidv4(), text}, ...prevTask];
      });
    }
  };  
  return (
    <View style={styles.container}>    
      <AddTask addTask={addTask} />
       <FlatList
          data={tasks}
          renderItem={({item}) => (
            <TaskList task={item} deleteTask={deleteTask} />
          )}
        />  
  )}
/>
    </View>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    flex: 1,
    paddingTop: 10,
  },
});

export default App;
```

I have taken your code from github and updated the code. You can check here
https://snack.expo.io/FbOC0J!MM

Comment: Wonderful thanks so much! Now, uuid is my only problem, uuidv4 is deprecated do you know how i can fix?

Comment: @CalebDockal Module in uuidv4 package are deprecated but from the code I see that you are using uuidv4 from uuid package. You are using the correct package / module. This is not deprecated.

Answer (score 0):

You need to add import React from 'react' at top of your code

Comment: ahh yes i apologize that was a formatting issue on my post, Ive edited it now so it reflects my actual code.